# SAS proc boxplot plot multiple variables

Tags: sas, boxplot

I was trying to use boxplot to exam the relationship between categorical and multiple numerical variables. I am using the breast cancer dataset from kaggle:
https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/breast-cancer-wisconsin-data

The data have column 'diagnosis' to be the classification criteria/dependent variable (which is categorical) and 30 other columns (all numeric) as explanatory variable such as 'radius_mean' 'radius_se' 'radius_worst' etc.

My question is instead of list all 30 variables by their names

'plot (radius_mean radius_se ... )*diagnosis;',

Is there a way to refer to all 30 variable names using a simpler command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the system view VCOLUMN to ask sas itself what fields it has

```
proc sql
    select name
    into :num_vars separated by ' '
    from SASHELP.VCOLUMN
    where libname = 'YOUR_LIB'              /* upper case */
      and memname = 'YOUR_MEMBER'           /* upper case */
      and name not in ('id', 'diagnosis'); /* correct case */
quit;
```

This creates a macro variable that lists all the variables you need

```
%put &num_vars;
```

Now use that

```
proc boxplot data=YOUR_LIB.YOUR_MEMBER;
    plot (&num_vars)*diagnosis; 
run;
```